# File is created, but not visible

Tags: c++

I have simple file create code, that creates file with record. existsf shows that file exists, but I can't see it in file system using explorer. What might be wrong?

```
#define FN "C:\Projects\src.txt"

using namespace std;


inline bool existsf (const std::string& name) {
    struct stat buffer;   
    return (stat (name.c_str(), &buffer) == 0); 
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::ofstream f;
    f.open(FN);
    if ( f.is_open() )
    {
        f<<"Some text here"<<std::endl;
        f.flush();
        f.close();
    }
    if (existsf(FN)) wcout<<"exist\n";
}
```

Comment: A decent compiler would notify you of your mistake with a warning such as `warning: unknown escape sequence: '\P'`. Assuming you've enabled warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 #define FN "C:\Projects\src.txt"
```

Backslash is the escape character in C++ string constants. You used backslashes to escape the `P` and the `s`, which doesn't do anything to them. So this is equivalent to:

```
 #define FN "C:Projectssrc.txt"
```

You wanted to escape the backlashes to produce literal backslashes in the string, like this:

```
 #define FN "C:\\Projects\\src.txt"
```

Comment: I don't think that you can count on `'\P' == 'P'`.